# How create parameterized tests with kotest and AnnotationSpec style

Tags: junit5, kotest

How to use data driven in Kotest with style *AnnotationSpec()*

Example for JUnit 5:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {1, 3, 5, -3, 15, Integer.MAX_VALUE}) // six numbers
void isOdd_ShouldReturnTrueForOddNumbers(int number) {
    assertTrue(Numbers.isOdd(number));
}
```

How can I do this in Kotest? This is what I tried to come up with:

```
class AnnotationSpecExample : AnnotationSpec() {

    @Test
    fun test1(value: Int) {
        value shouldBe 1
    }
}
```

I couldn't find documentation and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Annotation spec style is an easy way to migrate your JUnit tests to Kotest, but it doesn't have much to offer and I suggest that you use another more "Kotest-idiomatic" style instead, like `FunSpec`.

The counterpart of parameterized tests in Kotest would be [data driven testing](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/datatesting/data-driven-testing.html) in Kotest. In a `FunSpec` test, your example looks like this, using `withData` from the `kotest-framework-datatest` module:

```
class OddNumberTest : FunSpec({
    context("odd numbers") {
        withData(1, 3, 5, -3, 15, Integer.MAX_VALUE) { number ->
            number should beOdd()
        }
    }
})
```

The problem when you try to use Annotation Spec style here, is that you cannot use `withData` in a leaf scope, but only in root or container scopes, and each test in an Annotation spec is a leaf.

Comment: thank you, I will switch to another style.